# Addressing Odd-Length Mel Spectrogram Challenges in Variational Autoencoder Training Through Padding to Nearest Power of 2

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, librosa

I'm working on a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) for Mel spectrograms. The issue comes in when downsampling with conv2D in the encoder, as dealing with odd numbers makes audio reconstruction challenging in the decoder. Is there a method to transform the Mel spectrogram to avoid encountering odd values?

One approach I'm considering is to adjust the length of the spectrogram to the nearest power of 2 during training, but I'm uncertain if this is the best solution

I'm thinking of a possible solution where I add padding to the time length of the spectrogram if it's not a power of 2. For instance, if the time length is 226, I would pad it up to 256. This could help me prevent encountering odd values during the downsampling proces